how to configure GitLab Actions to trust the SSL certificate of the Maven server?
I need a step by step guide. Maybe is simple but I didn´t find clearly in internet or chatgpt.
I do mvn clean install in gitlab actions.
Before I added a server to the pom.xml
     </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>profile-releases</id>
            <url>https://enterprise.com.uy/repository</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
      </project>

But I have this problem:
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project web-user-test: Could not resolve dependencies for project uy.com.enterprise:web-user-test:jar:1.0.0: Failed to collect dependencies at uy.com.enterprise.ProxyISSO:jar:3.0.0: Failed to read artifact descriptor for uy.com.enterprise.ProxyISSO:jar:3.0.0: Could not transfer artifact uy.com.enterprise:ProxyISSO:pom:3.0.0 from/to desaint-releases (https://enterprise.com.uy/enterprise/repo): transfer failed for ...: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target -> [Help 1]

And I have the certificate cert001.crt on mi local PC.
Where should I put the certificate in gitlab actions?
I found that:
Modify your GitLab Actions workflow to use the environment variable. The enviroment variable is the whole certificate. But I find this solution somewhat clumsy.
The image in gitlab is:
image: maven:3.8.1-jdk-11

Add the certificate to the keystore of the JVM running here

GitHub Actions or GitLab CI?

There are several ways: 1st download the certificate or mount it in the container running Maven; or build a custom image for Maven with the certs already embedded in it and use this image in your CI.

GitLab CI @GaëlJ

@ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I know "which" is the solution, my question is "how" to do that, how can I add the certificate to the JVM running on the image?
Do a custom image is not an option for me, thanks.

@y.z you are not asking me, right?

If a custom image is not an option, then when running the image, your 1st steps before running Maven should be to download the certs and install them
